airflow-webserver-1 | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'params'
This error comes when I trigger dag from airflow.
with DAG(
        dag_id="read_data_from_db",
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args={
            "owner": "airflow",
            "retries": 0,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
            "start_date": datetime(2021, 12, 12),
            "on_success_callback": custom_success_function,
            "on_failure_callback": custom_failure_function
        },
        max_active_runs=dag_max_active_run,
        catchup=False) as f:
    report_making = PythonOperator(
        task_id='db_workflow',
        python_callable=read_data_from_db,
        execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=1400),
        # provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={"test_param": " This is a test param for report workflow."}
    )

This is my dag code
I am expecting DAG to run the function.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app                                                                                    
airflow-webserver-1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()                                                                                                                                       
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
airflow-webserver-1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)                                                                                                                                            
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
airflow-webserver-1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()                                                                                                                                                  
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request                                                                            
airflow-webserver-1  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/auth.py", line 47, in decorated                                                                              
airflow-webserver-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/decorators.py", line 125, in wrapper                                                                         
airflow-webserver-1  |     return f(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                     
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
airflow-webserver-1  |     return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                 
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1898, in trigger                                                                             
airflow-webserver-1  |     for k, v in dag.params.items():
airflow-webserver-1  | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'params'                                                                                                                       
airflow-webserver-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2024:11:58:29 +0000] "POST /trigger HTTP/1.1" 500 1538 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"                                                                                                                                                               
airflow-webserver-1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2024:11:58:30 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 243 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
airflow-webserver-1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2024:11:58:40 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 243 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
airflow-scheduler-1  | [2024-09-05T11:58:46.

Everything is healthy up and running, I am still getting the same error

During the dag creation you have to write with DAG (...) as dag. and then use dag variable.
